# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar la copia de una tabla automaticamente si modifico la tabla original?

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql

Mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo una tabla que se llama Estadisticas y otra que se llama copiaEstadisticas con todos los datos **`(create table copiaEstadistica as (select * from Estadisticas))`**

Lo que quiero hacer es un trigger o una funcion, no sé qué utilizar para que la tabla **copiaEstadistica** se actualice automaticamente cuando inserto o modifico los datos de **Estadisticas**.

[image: Esquema del modelo]

Comment: Se que esta no es la cuestión, pero ¿Para que quieres una tabla **copiaEstadistica** con esas características de clonado? como respaldo no valdría pues no servirá para recuperar datos y como tabla temporal añades mucho trabajo de mantenimiento en la db (una tabla + un procedimiento almacenado) ¿vale la pena esta solución para tu caso?

Comment: Es un ejercicio de clase el cual va mucho mas hayá de todo esto, el ejercicio consiste en que se miren los puntos, rebotes, etc... del jugador y se haga una media, si tiene mas de 20 puntos le sumo una estrella, mas de 5 rebotes otra estrella, pero claro, haciendo una media del total de todas las temporadas, entonces necesito esta copia para poder tratar los datos desde ella, ya que si lo hago de Estadisticas pues sale un error diciendo que la tabla está mutando.

Comment: @Fly Y tienes razón, el updating lo he hecho así rápido y está incorrecto, en cuanto tenga tiempo hago updating(temporada), updating(jugador), etc... En resumen un updating para cada campo y ya si estaría todo perfecto

Comment: ¿Has evaluado la posibilidad de usar [vistas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)? Seguro que puede encontrar muchos ejemplos por la red (https://www.anerbarrena.com/create-view-mysql-5101/), quizá eso te solucione el problema.

Comment: @Fly Pues no habia caido, muchas gracias, es que a uno entre java, plsql, xml, xquery, maquinas virtuales, etc... pues me falla ya la cabeza jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Los triggers son lo mas apropiado, te actualizaría sola la tabla de copia en cuanto hicieses algun cambio en la original

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insertEnTabla
AFTER INSERT on Estadisticas
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CopiaEstadisticas (Temporada, Jugador, Puntos_por_partido, Asistencias_por_partido, Tapones_por_partido, Rebotes_por_partido) VALUES (:NEW.Temporada, :NEW.Jugador, :NEW.Puntos_por_partido, :NEW.Asistencias_por_partido, :NEW.Tapones_por_partido, :NEW.Rebotes_por_partido);
END;
END insertEnTabla;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updateEnTabla
AFTER UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE CopiaEstadistica 
SET Temporada=:new.Temporada, 
  Jugador=:new.Jugador, 
  Puntos_por_partido=:NEW.Puntos_por_partido,
  Asistencias_por_partido=:NEW.Asistencias_por_partido, 
  Tapones_por_partido=:NEW.Tapones_por_partido,
  Rebotes_por_partido=:NEW.Rebotes_por_partido 
WHERE Jugador=:OLD.Jugador;
END;
END updateEnTabla;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger actualizaEstadisticas after insert or update on Estadisticas
for each row
declare
begin
if inserting then 
    insert into copiaEstadistica values(:new.Temporada, :new.jugador, :new.puntos_por_partido, :new.asistencias_por_partido,
    :new.tapones_por_partido, :new.rebotes_por_partido);
end if;

if updating then
    update copiaEstadistica set temporada=:new.Temporada, jugador=:new.jugador, puntos_por_partido=:new.puntos_por_partido,
    asistencias_por_partido=:new.asistencias_por_partido, tapones_por_partido=:new.tapones_por_partido,
    rebotes_por_partido=:new.rebotes_por_partido where jugador=:old.jugador;
end if;
end;
/
```

De esta manera cada vez que actualice o inserte datos en la tabla original, la copia también será modificada.